# Between Date Literals

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

How do I make this work in SQL Server (2005)?
The error message is 'Invalid column name' on the literals.

```
SELECT tstamp, GVEA_Load_Net_MWH 
  FROM DA.dbo.Oplog
 WHERE CAST(LEFT(tstamp,18) AS datetime) BETWEEN "01/01/2009 00:00:00" 
                                             AND "01/01/2010 00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the double quotes to single.

Comment: Thanks, it's always something simple.  I'll accept when the timer runs out.

Answer (score 2):

Like this for your example

```
SELECT tstamp, GVEA_Load_Net_MWH FROM DA.dbo.Oplog
WHERE CAST(LEFT(tstamp,18) AS datetime) BETWEEN '20090101' AND '20100101'
```

Notice the ISO safe and language safe YYYYMMDD format? Keep in mind that this query is not SARGable and will not use an index

Also take a look [How Does Between Work With Dates In SQL Server?](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-does-between-work-with-dates-in-sql-) to understand why between might sometimes not give you the results you epect

Comment: Thanks, will the dates in that format come with an implicit 00:00:00, and be able to handle all the times inbetween?